# segmentation fault in ONP

Tags: c, algorithm

Here is my code for the problem id-4 in spoj, it is running perfectly in ideone.com but in spoj its showing segmentation fault, I am unable to find out the bug.Please help. I have used stacks to implement it.Thanks in advance.
exp is the input string, and out is the output string, int l keeps track of the index of output string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//declarations
int top = 0;
void push(char ch); 
char pop();
int prec(char c);
char stack[20];
char out[20];
int l = 0;

int main() {
    char exp[20];
    int x, t;
    char temp;
    int i = 0;
    scanf("%d", &t);      //no. of test cases
    while (t--) {
      l=0;
        scanf("%s", exp);
        stack[0] = '(';   //initially pushing '('
        x = strlen(exp);
        exp[x] = ')';     //for completion of statement

        for (i = 0; i < x + 1; i++) {          
            if (exp[i] == '+' || exp[i] == '-' ||
                exp[i] == '/' || exp[i] == '*' || exp[i] == '^') {   //operators
                while (prec(exp[i]) < prec(stack[top])) { //checking precedence
                    out[l] = pop();
                    l++;
                }
                push(exp[i]);
            } else
            if (exp[i] == '(') {
                push(exp[i]);
            } else
            if (exp[i] == ')') {
                while (stack[top] != '(') {
                    out[l] = pop();
                    l++;
                }
                temp = pop();     //to throw out '('
            } else {
                out[l] = exp[i];  //variables
                l++;
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            printf("%c", out[i]);         //output
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void push(char c) {            //push operation on stack
    if (top >= 19) {        
    } else {
        top++;
        stack[top] = c;
    }
    return;
}

char pop() {              //pop operation on stack
    char t;
    if (top <= -1) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        t = stack[top];
        top--;
        return t;
    }
}

int prec(char c) {                           //precedence check
    if (c == 94) { return 5; }
    else if (c == 47) { return 4; }
    else if (c == 42) { return 3; }
    else if (c == 43) { return 2; }
    else if (c == 45) { return 1; }
    else { return 0; }
}
```

Comment: What is your input ?

Comment: You should try to simplify this code by splitting it up into several small functions.

Comment: Single-letter var names, no details of debugging already done, no test inputs shown, no clue as to which line generates the fault.  Just not good.  Please provide more information.

Comment: Sorry sir @martin james,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buffer to read the expression is very small: `char exp[20];` and you do not protect `scanf` for buffer overflow.

Sphere Online Judge specifies:

> **Input**
>
> > t [the number of expressions <= 100]
> >     expression [length <= 400]
> >     [other expressions]

You should use a larger stack, at least 100, a larger buffer and use:

```
char exp[402];
...
scanf("%400s", exp);
```

Also test the return value from `scanf("%d", &t)`, just in case they give you purposely erroneous input.

Comment: I did it, still showing same error

Comment: Did you also use Rabbid76's fixes?

Comment: Did you make `out` 400 bytes as well?  Did you enlarge the stack and update `push` accordingly?

Comment: yes i did, stack, exp and out all of size 400

Comment: You are not supposed to fix the code in the question, but did you also change `push()`?  It is still showing `if (top >= 19)`. You did not protect `scanf` with `scanf("%400s", exp);`

Comment: oh!..sorry, yes i did

Comment: tysm sir! i have forgotten to add top>=400, sorry!, but i just saw scanf part only

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if `top` is greater or equal `0`:

```
while( top >= 0 && prec(exp[i])<prec(stack[top])){
//     ^^^^^^^^
....
while( top >= 0 && stack[top]!='('){
//     ^^^^^^^^
```

The segmentation fault occurs, because you access to `stack[top]` and `top` is less than `0`. Apart form this I recommend to increase the size of arrays `exp` and `out` coherently.

Comment: Your suggestion is welcome, but `stack[-1]` is only accessed if the expression contains extra `)`s.

Comment: I did it, still showing same error

Comment: t for no. of test cases and then string of expression,ex 1 and a+b